# Servlet does not work on IntellJ

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I have a problem creating a simple Servlet with IntelliJ. On eclipse the code above works fine and it show me the right output. 
But on IntelliJ (and a tomcat correctly setted) it show me on output a simple html page with "$Title$" as title and "$END$" as body and I can't understand why.
Someone can help me please?

```
package ServerTest;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;

@WebServlet(name = "Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public Servlet()
    {
        super();
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "mypass");
            PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT first_name FROM actor");


            // pstmt.setString(parameter position, value)


            ResultSet result= pstmt.executeQuery();
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            out.println("<HTML>");
            out.println("<BODY>");
            out.println("<H1> Risultato: </H1>");
            while (result.next())
            {
                out.println("<P>");

                out.println(result.getString("first_name"));
                out.println("</P>");
            }
            out.println("</BODY>");
            out.println("</HTML>");
            result.close();
            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Errore nell'esecuzione della query");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Impossibile caricare il driver");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is not another servlet with higher priority that do that?  Can you set a break point to probe that you use this servlet ?

Comment: Nope, the code can't reach the breakpoint. So what I have to do?

Comment: Wait, breakpoint does not work on webserver.

Comment: if you use a idea managed server they you can start it with debug mode. If you use the free idea version, then you start your server outside idea. You need to use the remote debugging. If you add a "Remote" launcher in idea, it will tell you the parameter to add when launching the server.

Comment: Problem solved. Damn xml.

Comment: Ok, you're good to delete this.